# searching a string value in a non-numeric column

Tags: python, pandas, string, categorical-data

In the data frame that contains 20000 chess matches, there is a column named `opening_name`.

All values in this column are strings like this:

```
1        Nimzowitsch Defense: Kennedy Variation
2         King's Pawn Game: Leonardis Variation
3        Queen's Pawn Game: Zukertort Variation
4                              Philidor Defense
                          ...                  
20053                             Dutch Defense
20054                              Queen's Pawn
20055           Queen's Pawn Game: Mason Attack
20056                              Pirc Defense
20057           Queen's Pawn Game: Mason Attack
```

In this column, there are almost a hundred values that have similar names, similar names like  `Sicilian defence` and  `Sicilian defence: dragon variation` I want to access all these values that start with the string  `Sicilian defence`. How can I do that?

Comment: Done use apply for this! you should be using a str function instead!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding, the string part before : is the starting string and the value after it is the variation.

Step 1 : Extract the prefix value for all the rows by splitting on :

```
df['base_term']=df.opening_name.apply(lambda x: x.split(":")[0])
```

This shall return a new column with values or the start string.

Step 2 : Retrieve the rows that have a given starting string , for example "Sicilian defence".

```
res = df.loc[df.base_term=='Sicilian defence']
```

res is the dataframe with rows that have opening_name beginning with 'Sicilian defence'

Comment: Thank you so much, this should work. I totally forgot about using lambda with a split function.

Comment: Why would you use an inefficient apply funciton

Comment: this is not a good answer. you can solve this significantly faster with a vectorized approach. the whole point of str methods is that you can do these processes without using apply funcitons.

Answer (score 0):

Try a vectorized approach with `str`. **Using `apply` and `lambda` functions are highly inefficient.**

```
df.fname = df.opening_name.str.split(':').str[0]
```

```
0    Nimzowitsch Defense
1        Kings Pawn Game
2       Queens Pawn Game
3       Philidor Defense
dtype: object
```

---

You can fetch it by simply by using `.loc`-

```
df.loc[df.fname=='Sicilian defence']
```